# pdoResources в ModX Revolution дублирует чанки при выводе

Tags: modx, pdoresource

При выводе чанка в шаблон через pdoResources чанк на странице дублируется.

Сам чанк вывожу так:

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`0`
    &depth=`0`
    &tpl =`Chunk_Name`
    &includeTVs=`TV_Name`
]]
```

При том пробовал удалять, создавать другие чанки, или менять чанки на другие, уже существующие, все выводятся по несколько штук.

Так выглядит чанк:

```
<hr class="line-roduct">
<div class="feature__title-container">
    <h3 class="feature__title">
        Преимущества
    </h3>
    <div class="feature__content">
        [[+tv.Контент]]
    </div>
</div>
```

Если выводить чанк стандартным [[$Chunk_Name]] то всё получается как надо, но так не подтягивается TV поле, которое находится в чанке, а оно мне нужно.

**Важно!** 
*Интересное наблюдение сейчас выявил. Если убрать всю HTML разметку из чанка, оставив только [[+tv.Контент]], чанк перестаёт дублироваться и добавляется корректно. Но если написать любой абсолютно текст, по типу "Тест", чанк снова начинает дублироваться.*

Comment: попробуйте вызвать сниппет некешированным. Какие еще ресурсы лежат в корне сайта, нет ли симлинков? Нет ли плагинов/JS кода, перехватывающих что-нибудь?

Comment: Некешированным через "!"? Пробовал, бесполезно. Касательно JS кода, он есть, но привязан он к стилям CSS, даже если их убрать, будет дублирование чанка. Если сделать чанк пустым и добавить просто слово "Тест", чанк так же будет дублироваться. При том изначально он дублировался в 6 позиций, теперь их 8, хотя вроде ничего поменять я не успел...

Comment: интересно. попробуйте еще передать в вызов сниппета такой параметр: &return=`json` посмотрите, добываемые сниппетом сырые данные уже задвоены, или речь именно о задвоении на этапе отображения?

Comment: Получился большой блок с текстом, есть возможность в чат какой-то с Вами перейти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать точно три параметра:
&resources, &depth и &parents
и выбрать нужные ресурсы(ресурс)